# MATLAB sort matrix by one row

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have matrix lets say `MAT of size 2*n`

I want to sort the matrix by row num 2

BUT to keep each info from row 1 to its row 2 info

```
prev
C K A L E Y B
4 2 1 3 6 7 7

and after sort
A K L C E Y B
1 2 3 4 6 7 7
```

any idea?

Comment: Your example matrix include characters and numbers, which is impossible in MatLab, please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

you can use the second output argument of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[~, si] = sort(MAT(2,:));
res = MAT(:,si);
```